# Installing NVidia 410 and CUDA 10 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics, cuda

I am asking myself how to install the latest proprietary NVidia-driver (410.72) with the latest CUDA (10) for Ubuntu server 18.04 (Kernel 4.15.0-29) with a Tesla V100.

```
$ lspci | grep NVIDIA
3b:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GV100 [Tesla V100 PCIe] (rev a1)
```

Apparently, the free driver (nouveau) is installed as of now. As far as I understand, I will need to install the proprietary driver instead.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. Integrated Matrox G200eW3 Graphics Controller [102b:0536] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Integrated Matrox G200eW3 Graphics Controller [1028:0715]
    Kernel driver in use: mgag200
--
3b:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GV100 [Tesla V100 PCIe] [10de:1db4] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GV100 [Tesla V100 PCIe] [10de:1214]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

$ sudo lshw -numeric -C display
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. [102B:536]
       vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. [102B]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=mgag200 latency=64 maxlatency=32 mingnt=16
       resources: irq:16 memory:91000000-91ffffff memory:92808000-9280bfff memory:92000000-927fffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE:1DB4]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:38280-3827f iomemory:382c0-382bf memory:ab000000-abffffff memory:382800000000-382bffffffff memory:382c00000000-382c01ffffff

$ dpkg -l nvidia*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                          Version             Architecture        Description
+++-=============================-===================-===================-================================================================
un  nvidia-common                 <none>              <none>              (no description available)
un  nvidia-prime                  <none>              <none>              (no description available)
```

I've read several guides, most of them using outdated versions and at that point, I am not so sure anymore which way to follow.

I'd like to go with the (apparently official) PPA graphics-drivers, yet trying to add the repo fails:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~graphics-drivers/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~graphics-drivers' user or team does not exist.
```

While the repository actually DOES exist: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages

The official repository of NVidia (https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/) already lists the 410-driver for Ubuntu 18.04, yet cant be added for installation via apt-get (?).

I'd like to NOT *manually* install CUDA and graphics card drivers from the NVidia website, as I'd need to manually update/fix everything then in the future. Hence: is there a way to get the PPA working? Or will I need to manually install the drivers? Or is there even another way?

Comment: The command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` is correct but you probably typed it incorrectly like "~graphics-drivers". If not you have much more serious problems with your system.

Comment: I am sure I did not type it incorrectly. Maybe there's some problem with the firewall.

Comment: I would try again with copy/paste, just in case. But yes, I've heard APT has issues with proxies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it will apparently remain unclear what the error was, as the server crashed and needs to be re-setup as it wont reboot properly.

Anyhow, I manually added the repositories by adding the URL to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and adding the key manually via `apt-key add file.pub`, where I had manually copied the entire public key to `file.pub` beforehand.

This worked and allowed me to install from said repository, even though the "normal" way still wouldn't work.